# gcc built-in __atomic or __sync functions cannot provide consistent access to a global variable

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gcc

I have a global integer (`input_level` field of `struct LogBufferDescriptor` in the program below) which will be written by a thread, and read by more than 1 thread(s). I use gcc built-in `__atomic_store_n()` / `__atomic_load_n()` functions or legacy `__sync_lock_test_and_set()` / `__sync_fetch_and_add()` functions to access it. But neither can provide consistent result.

Neither gcc built-in __atomic functions nor legacy __sync functions can provide consistent access to the integer. Current, only semaphore and pthread_mutex works OK.

```
/*
gcc -g -o simulate_case simulate_case.c -lpthread
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define LOG_BUFFER_INPUT_LEVEL_DEFAULT     2
#define LOG_BUFFER_INPUT_LEVEL_NO_PRINTS   6
#define MS_TO_US(ms)                ((ms) * 1000)
#define TIMEOUT_MS                  100
#define SYNC_GCC_SYNC


typedef struct LogBufferDescriptor
{
    int                          input_level;
    pthread_mutex_t              log_buffer_lock;
    pthread_mutex_t              input_level_lock;
    sem_t                        input_level_sem;
} LogBufferDescriptor;

static LogBufferDescriptor       G_log_buffer;


/********** choose one implementation by defining corresponding macro ***********/

#ifdef SYNC_NONE
static void print_sync_mechanism(void)
{
    printf("Sync mechanism = NONE\n");
}
static void set_input_level(int level)
{
    G_log_buffer.input_level = level;
}
static int get_input_level(void)
{
    return G_log_buffer.input_level;
}
#endif

#ifdef SYNC_GCC_MUTEX
static void print_sync_mechanism(void)
{
    printf("Sync mechanism = MUTEX\n");
}
static void set_input_level(int level)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&G_log_buffer.input_level_lock);
    G_log_buffer.input_level = level;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&G_log_buffer.input_level_lock);
}
static int get_input_level(void)
{
    int level;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&G_log_buffer.input_level_lock);
    level = G_log_buffer.input_level;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&G_log_buffer.input_level_lock);
    return level;
}
#endif

#ifdef SYNC_SEM
static void print_sync_mechanism(void)
{
    printf("Sync mechanism = semaphore\n");
}
static void set_input_level(int level)
{
    sem_wait(&G_log_buffer.input_level_sem);
    G_log_buffer.input_level = level;
    sem_post(&G_log_buffer.input_level_sem);
}
static int get_input_level(void)
{
    int level;
    sem_wait(&G_log_buffer.input_level_sem);
    level = G_log_buffer.input_level;
    sem_post(&G_log_buffer.input_level_sem);
    return level;
}
#endif

#ifdef SYNC_GCC_ATOMIC
static void print_sync_mechanism(void)
{
    printf("Sync mechanism = GCC ATOMIC\n");
}
static void set_input_level(int level)
{
    __atomic_store_n(&G_log_buffer.input_level, level, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}
static int get_input_level(void)
{
    return __atomic_load_n(&G_log_buffer.input_level, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}
#endif

#ifdef SYNC_GCC_SYNC
static void print_sync_mechanism(void)
{
    printf("Sync mechanism = GCC LEGACY SYNC\n");
}
static void set_input_level(int level)
{
    __sync_lock_test_and_set(&G_log_buffer.input_level, level);
}
static int get_input_level(void)
{
    return __sync_fetch_and_add(&G_log_buffer.input_level, 0);
}
#endif


/********** log collecting thread ***********/

static void dump_log_buffer()
{
    set_input_level(LOG_BUFFER_INPUT_LEVEL_NO_PRINTS);  // do not allow input during dumping

    pthread_mutex_lock(&G_log_buffer.log_buffer_lock);    
    usleep(MS_TO_US(TIMEOUT_MS + 1));  // simulate dumping log buffer
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&G_log_buffer.log_buffer_lock);

    set_input_level(LOG_BUFFER_INPUT_LEVEL_DEFAULT);  // restore
}

static void *log_thread(void *arg)
{
    unsigned long count = 0;
    int seedp = 1;
    srand(seedp);
    for (; ;)
    {
        dump_log_buffer();
        usleep(MS_TO_US(rand_r(&seedp) % 5));
        ++count;
        if (count % 160 == 0) printf("Dumped %lu times of logs.\n", count);  // prove thread is running
    }
    return NULL;
}

/********** business thread ***********/

static void write_log(int severity)
{
    static unsigned int count = 0;
    struct timeval      start, end;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    if (severity < get_input_level()) return;  // abort
    pthread_mutex_lock(&G_log_buffer.log_buffer_lock);
    usleep(100);  // simulate writing to log buffer
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&G_log_buffer.log_buffer_lock);

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    int diff = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000 + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000;  // in ms
    if (diff >= TIMEOUT_MS) printf("***** Business delayed %u time(s)! *****\n", ++count);
}

/* business thread prints logs randomly */
static void *business_thread(void *arg)
{
    unsigned long count = 0;
    for (; ;)
    {
        write_log(LOG_BUFFER_INPUT_LEVEL_DEFAULT);
        ++count;
        if (count % 131072000 == 0) printf("Printed %lu lines of logs.\n", count);  // prove thread is running
    }
    return NULL;
}

/********** init ***********/

static void init()
{
    G_log_buffer.input_level = LOG_BUFFER_INPUT_LEVEL_DEFAULT;
    pthread_mutex_init(&G_log_buffer.log_buffer_lock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&G_log_buffer.input_level_lock, NULL);
    sem_init(&G_log_buffer.input_level_sem, 0, 1);  // binary semaphore
}

static void deinit()
{
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&G_log_buffer.log_buffer_lock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&G_log_buffer.input_level_lock);
    sem_destroy(&G_log_buffer.input_level_sem);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    init();
    print_sync_mechanism();

    pthread_t thread_id1, thread_id2;
    pthread_create (&thread_id1, NULL, &log_thread, NULL);
    pthread_create (&thread_id2, NULL, &business_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id2, NULL);

    deinit();
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked `input_level` before trying to lock the `log_buffer_lock`, and `input_level` is protected. In theory, business should not be delayed (due to waiting for `log_buffer_lock` mutex).

But it actually delayed. Program output when using gcc legacy __sync functions:

```
$ ./simulate_case
Sync mechanism = GCC LEGACY SYNC
......
Dumped 2080 times of logs.
Printed 5373952000 lines of logs.
***** Business delayed 1 time(s)! *****
```

OS and gcc info:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
$ uname -a
Linux *** 3.17.8-13.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 28 20:56:38 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)
```

Also happened on a Ubuntu machine (Windows 10 Linux Subsystem):

```
$ uname -a
Linux N-5CG8205MFD 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS \n \l
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Comment: From the GCC docs: "Note that the ‘__atomic’ builtins assume that programs will conform to the C++11 memory model. In particular, they assume that programs are free of data races. See the C++11 standard for detailed requirements."

Comment: I *think* you might have a data race but someone more knowledgeable in C could confirm this. Your `init()` function issues a plain write to `G_log_buffer.input_level`. You should make the write atomic. On the other hand, I *think* `pthread_create()` contains the necessary memory barriers to synchronize the write with later reads.

Comment: There's a window of opportunity between your checking of the input level and acquiring the mutex. This means that reading `LOG_BUFFER_INPUT_LEVEL_DEFAULT` only means the mutex wasn't locked yet at that time, and not that it won't be locked at the next instant. Maybe try using `pthread_mutex_trylock` and rechecking the level if it fails?

Comment: Instead of relying on raising and lowering the level and aborting if the level is raised, why not just use `pthread_mutex_timedlock()` to make sure the business thread is not blocked too long?

Comment: Hi @Eric the `init()` function is called at the beginning of `main()`, where other threads are not created yet. It is safe to use a plain write there.

Comment: @Eric the design is to use `pthread_mutex_timedlock()`, but here I just want to show the problem of atomic functions. If the protection to `input_level` works, business thread won't even have an opportunity to lock `log_buffer_lock`.

Comment: Hi @Hasturkun thank you for your suggestion. I think this can be a workaround. A true fix is more appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your comments.

When I created 2 business threads, even binary semaphore and mutex cannot guarantee no timeout. After adding log before and after locking/unlocking the `log_buffer_lock`, I found the reason:

```
# prefix B = business thread, 155 and 156 below; L = log collecting thread, 154 below.
# first column is sequence.
1D <00:24:49.617510> tid 156; B will lock.   # at this time, input level is 2
1E <00:24:49.617995> tid 155; B will unlock.
1F <00:24:49.617998> tid 154; L will lock.   # log collecting thread acquired mutex, even thread 156 waits first.
20 <00:24:49.618004> tid 154; L locked.
21 <00:24:49.618005> tid 155; B unlocked.
22 <00:24:49.719956> tid 154; L will unlock.
23 <00:24:49.719974> tid 154; L unlocked.
24 <00:24:49.720066> tid 155; B locked without waiting.
25 <00:24:49.721051> tid 155; B will unlock.
26 <00:24:49.721065> tid 155; B unlocked.
27 <00:24:49.721069> tid 156; B locked.      # finally thread 156 got the mutex.
28 <00:24:49.721073> tid 155; B will lock.
29 <00:24:49.721538> tid 156; B will unlock.
2A <00:24:49.721561> tid 156; B unlocked.
2B <00:24:49.721644> tid 155; B locked.
2C <00:24:49.722047> tid 155; B will unlock.
2D <00:24:49.722083> tid 155; B unlocked.
2E <00:24:49.722093> tid 155; B locked without waiting.
2F <00:24:49.722119> tid 156; ***** Business delayed 1 time(s)! *****
```

When there are >= 2 threads waiting for the same mutex, it cannot be determined that which will get the mutex first, regardless of its priority (I tried to set business thread's scheduling policy to REALTIME and priority to 99. This did not mitigate.) If `log_buffer_lock` is acquired by business thread 155, and both business thread 156 and log collecting thread are waiting, kernel may give the mutex to log collecting thread after it is released. In such situation, business thread 156 is starved and times out.

@Hasturkun you are right, there is a window between checking of the input level and acquiring the mutex.

- When there is only ONE business thread, using `pthread_mutex_trylock()` and rechecking the input level if it fails will work, because if `pthread_mutex_trylock()` fails, we can 100% sure it is aqcuired by log collecting thread.
- When there are >= 2 business threads, this will not work, because `log_buffer_lock` may be not only acquired by log collecting thread, but also by another business thread.

So this issue is not strong relevant to gcc builtin atomic functions. To fix it, `pthread_mutex_timedlock()` is inevitable. Using the following `write_log()` function, timeout did not happen for 1h even with no protection to `input_level`.

```
    static void write_log(int severity)
    {
        static unsigned int count = 0;
        struct timeval      start, end;

        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

        if (severity < get_input_level()) return;  // abort

        #if BUSINESS_THREADS_COUNT == 1
        if (0 != pthread_mutex_trylock(&G_log_buffer_desc.log_buffer_lock))
        {
            // `log_buffer_lock` is 100% acquired by log collecting thread.
            if (severity < get_input_level()) return;  // abort
            else {
                papillon_log("B will lock.\n");
                pthread_mutex_lock(&G_log_buffer_desc.log_buffer_lock);
                papillon_log("B locked.\n");
            }
        }
        else papillon_log("B locked without waiting.\n");
        #else
        // When there are >= 2 business threads, testing `log_buffer_lock` will not work, because it may be not only acquired by log collecting thread, but also by another business thread.
        struct timespec wait_time;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME , &wait_time);
        wait_time.tv_nsec += (TIMEOUT_MS / 10) * 1000;  // in ns
        papillon_log("B will lock.\n");
        if (0 != pthread_mutex_timedlock(&G_log_buffer_desc.log_buffer_lock, &wait_time)) return;  // abort
        papillon_log("B locked.\n");
        #endif  /* BUSINESS_THREADS_COUNT */

        usleep(100);  // to simulate writing to the log buffer
        papillon_log("B will unlock.\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&G_log_buffer_desc.log_buffer_lock);
        papillon_log("B unlocked.\n");

        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        int diff = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000 + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000;  // in ms
        if (diff >= TIMEOUT_MS) papillon_log("***** Business delayed %u time(s)! *****\n", ++count);
    }
```